# Specific ordering SQL Command

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have a table similar to:

```
ID    Name
1     Test
2     Contest
3     Fittest
4     Testament
```

Is there a MySQL query I could use with ordering to allow it to display a specific word first?

For example, users are searching for the word "Test". I have a statement similar to "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE NAME LIKE '%Test%'". Could I display results to show things that START with Test begin first followed by everything else, while everything is still in alphabetical order.

So output would be:

```
Test
Testament
Contested
Fittest
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will put your words that begin with Test at the top, and sort those words plus the remainder of the list in alphabetical order..

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN name LIKE 'test%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC, name ASC
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE NAME LIKE '%Test%'
order by case when name like 'test%' then 0 else 1 end
```

Comment: This appears to work for the first part, putting "Test%" things first, however not everything is alphabetical.

Example, output is similar to:
Test
Testament
Fittest
Contested